# Resizing a Godaddy Trust Seal

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to resize the Godaddy trust seal on my website. The JavaScript code for this seal is:

```
<span id="cdSiteSeal1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//tracedseals.starfieldtech.com/siteseal/get?scriptId=cdSiteSeal1&amp;cdSealType=Seal1&amp;
        sealId=55e4ye7y7mb7368e3408b5125e4c097vfwzy7mb7355e4ye7f334dddf408b66d1">
    </script>
</span>
```

It displays a trust seal with the current date linked to some info about my site, however the seal is much smaller than I would like.  Could do a workaround of just downloading the image, resizing and linking, but this won't allow it to update with the current date.

Not very familiar at all with javascript, but any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could **probably** force a style with CSS:

```
#cdSiteSeal1 IMG {
    width: 50px !Important;
    height: 50px !Important;
}
```

However, altering a seal is possibly a violation of the terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

You could also force the style with `jQuery` and if it does not work using `setTimeout() callback`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#cdSiteSeal1 img").height(number);
   $("#cdSiteSeal1 img").width(number);
}
```